# How to make a dynamically created field/element required?

Tags: javascript, dom

My attempt was:

```
     -- new field id and name: fruit
     var cellText = document.createElement('input');
     cellText.type = 'text';
     cellText.id = 'fruit';
     cellText.name = 'fruit';
     cellText.required = true;
     cellText.message = "Please enter something for the newly created Fruit field";
```

Tested with Firefox 19 for Windows and Chrome 26, neither working.
What's the correct syntax for it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `cellText.required = "required";`